# Powerpoint 2013 datasource for chart

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I would like to add a chart in my ppt 2013 presentation that links to data in a mysql query, so that every time the slide runs it updates the data in the chart.

Is this possible via vba scripting or do I need to look at embedding excel charts and data sources?

Many thanks

Dave

Comment: "every time the slide runs" ... does that mean every time the presentation is opened, or every time you visit the slide in an already-open presentation?  In either case, you'll need to write code for this.  And embedding won't help; embedded content updates only when you doubleclick to activate it, and what gets activated is the version of the data contained in the presentation file, not anything external.

Comment: I do mean every time the slide is visited whilst the slideshow is running

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For starters, you can use this to trigger a macro on each slide change:

```
Sub OnSlideShowPageChange(ByVal SSW As SlideShowWindow)

  MsgBox "You've arrived at slide " & CStr(SSW.View.Slide.SlideIndex)

End Sub
```

You'd have to look at each shape on the slide to determine whether it's a chart or pre-name the charts and use a function that traps the error if you ask for a shape name that doesn't exist.

What you do next would depend on what type of chart it is (Excel, PPT, MSGraph or something else).